# How can I install only install_requires but not the lib with setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I want to make a docker image for my OpenERP.

I have modified OpenERP source code and I want to use the image to run it. So the image should be *"libs ready"* but have no OpenERP pre-installed on it.

The OpenERP project has a [setup.py](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/7.0/setup.py). I'd like to install all the libs specified by `install_requires`.

In other words, I'd like to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` if there it is. Unfortunately, the `pip` and `apt-get` just install quite different versions of libs. So it would be quite a lot of work to make the requirements.txt file myself, nor to maintain it.

What choices do I have?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to install your fork? pip can install from a git repository, so `pip install git+git://my/hosted/repo@branch` will install dependencies + your version of OpenERP

Comment: @kalhartt I want a clean docker image. The source code is on my host machine and I will mount it to the container. I'm not using OpenERP, I'm developing it.

Comment: I see. Since openerp includes a requirements.txt, is `pip install $(curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/odoo/odoo/8.0/requirements.txt)` an option?

Comment: I'm with v7. Happy to see that this will not be a problem in the future.

Comment: Tight spot then, I do think your best option is to maintain a requirements.txt yourself. Maybe someone else has a better option.